# Categorise data by using group by in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a doubt similar to the question posted in the link [SQL - columns for different categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611542/sql-columns-for-different-categories). I have student table with Student Name, Midterm Grade and Final Grade as dipicted in GradeTable below.

```
StName  MidTermGrade    FinalGrade
St1         1               1
St2         2               1
St3         2               3
St4         1               3
St5         1               1
St6         2               3
St7         2               2
St8         1               1
St9         2               2
St10        2               3
St11        3               1
St12        2               1
St13        3               3
St14        3               2
St15        1               2
```

This data needs to be categorised using SQL query to generate the output so that all the grading and Student Names fall in one query output which i can paste in word/excel and provide it as report.

```
FinalGrade  MidTermGrade1   MidTermGrade2   MidTermGrade3
   1        St1             St2             St11
   1        St5             St12    
   1        St8     
   2        St15            St7             St14
   2                        St9 
   3        St4             St3             St13
   3        St6 
   3                        St10
```

Please help and advise if this can be achieved.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? mysql, MSSQL..?

Comment: I don't get it.   The column says midtermgrade1, but it seems to contain a student name.  Can you better describe what you want?

Comment: The basic idea is the row and column grouping will happen based on the grade obtained by the student. So the end result would be a matrix of Final Grading(Row)  V/s Mid Term Grading(Column) with Student Names placed in the respective cells. I am not sure, if such kind of grouping can be done in SQL. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it is easy/possibly to get what you need, but maybe this is good enough:

```
select FinalGrade, MidtermGrade, group_concat(StName) from GradeTable group by FinalGrade, MidtermGrade;
```

Then you can easily do the rest with code..?