# Returning rows as columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

I'd love to do it as a single query, but I think it's going to require a cursor.  If I can't do it as a single query, I'd like to output the results as a SYS_REFCURSOR.  A simplified example:

#### PRODUCT

```
ID   NAME         Part Number   SKU
------------------------------------
1    Widgetizer     150         1001
2    Widgetizer200  200         1002
3    WidgetizerDlx  250         1003
```

#### PRODUCT_SPEC

```
P_ID   NAME     VALUE
----------------------------
1      WEIGHT    5
1      HEIGHT    10
1      VERSION   1
1      COLOR     RED
2      WEIGHT    7
2      HEIGHT    10
2      VERSION   2
2      COLOR     BLUE
```

Query:

For each product with SKU less than 1003, return:

```
Product name, part #, SKU, WEIGHT, HEIGHT, COLOR
```

Comment: Too bad you can't use 11g in which Oracle has introduced pivot queries (http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Transpose Rows as Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099198/sql-transpose-rows-as-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally referred to as a pivot query.

```
select p.name, p.partnum, p.sku,
       max( case when s.name='WEIGHT' then s.value else null end ) weight,
       max( case when s.name='HEIGHT' then s.value else null end ) height,
       max( case when s.name='COLOR'  then s.value else null end ) color
from product p join product_spec s on p.id = s.p_id
where sku <= 1003
group by p.name, p.partnum, p.sku
```

Comment: The wages of EAV is writing really gnarly queries.