# Postgresql - how to groups rows and convert some rows to columns

Tags: postgresql, rows

I have a database that is something like the following:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| student_id |  subject  | test score |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|          3 | math      |         78 |
|          3 | physics   |         66 |
|          3 | english   |         98 |
|          2 | math      |         76 |
|          2 | physics   |         57 |
|          2 | geology   |         87 |
|          2 | english   |         99 |
|          1 | math      |         86 |
|          1 | physics   |         85 |
|          1 | astronomy |         89 |
|          1 | history   |         77 |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to group the subject_ids. The labels in the second column would become columns, and the new rows would be the scores. So it should look something like this:

```
+------------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| student_id | math | physics | english | geology | astronomy |
| 1          | 86   | 85      |         |         | 89        |
| 2          | 76   | 57      | 99      | 87      |           |
| 3          | 78   | 66      | 98      |         |           |
+------------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: mvp, thanks for the correction, how did you do that?

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow! You should read more about [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), it will be useful here and on many other sites, like github. Also, be sure to search first before asking - many questions have already been asked before

Comment: Do you actually want to change the database schema or just want a select statement that will output like the second example?

Comment: Search for `crosstab` and/or `pivot`.

Comment: [My go-to answer for crosstab queries.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: Thx for the info, the link above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099198/sql-transpose-rows-as-columns) is exactly what I was looking for. I did find it in a search before I posted my question but saw his 2 tables that he wanted combined and thought those answers didn't apply, I didn't realize that the 2nd table was extraneous. I did just want a SELECT statement, not to change the underlying structure. After looking at the "markdown syntax" link I'm still not clear what to use for a SQL-like table. I tried several of the formatting options to try to get my ascii to display properly.