# SQL (postgres) to join over a variable number of subselects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

- shop {'ID','NAME'}
- product {'ID','NAME'}
- orders {'SHOP_ID','PRODUCT_ID','QTY'}

The `orders` table is referencing to `product.id` for sold products at shop with `shop.id`.

I would like to create a an sql view that selects top 10 products per shop. Thus I wish result table to have 10 rows (one per rank) and as many columns as there exist shop ids in the `shop` table, with the to 10 sellers for the shop in each column.

Getting the top ten products for each shop is easy. Its also easy to get this for a fixed number of n shops by repeating and joining the selects to get this from a single shop, but I don't know how to do this for a variable number of shops. 
I searched for similar examples and my feeling is, that this should be possible with a *common table expression* but I don't get it.

So the question is:

*How to join a variable number of sub selects in a loop or similar construct*

Example how the result should look like:

```
'RANK' 'Berlin' 'Hamburg' 'München'
  1        2        3         4
  2        .        .         .
  .        .        .         .
  .        .        .         .
  9        .        .         .
 10        .        .         x
```

Where the numbers are product IDs of the top 10 sellers. 
I.e. the columns are created like xx.product_id as 'Berlin'.

Answer (score 1):

The following produces the transpose of what you are looking for:

```
    select shop_id, 
    max(case when r = 1 then product_id else 0 end) as p_1,
    max(case when r = 2 then product_id else 0 end) as p_2,
    max(case when r = 3 then product_id else 0 end) as p_3,
    max(case when r = 4 then product_id else 0 end) as p_4,
    max(case when r = 5 then product_id else 0 end) as p_5,
    max(case when r = 6 then product_id else 0 end) as p_6,
    max(case when r = 7 then product_id else 0 end) as p_7,
    max(case when r = 8 then product_id else 0 end) as p_8,
    max(case when r = 9 then product_id else 0 end) as p_9,
    max(case when r = 10 then product_id else 0 end) as p_10
    from
    (
        select shop_id, product_id, sum(qty) as sales, 
        row_number() over (partition by shop_id order by sum(qty) desc) as r
        from orders
        group by shop_id, product_id
    )group by shop_id
```

To transpose this you can use [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html), but this requires you to know the number of shops in advance.  Databases aren't generally designed to have tables with an unknown number of columns.  A possible approach would be to create a function similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26061154/1961252).

Comment: This gets the data, but I would really like to know how to get these in the transposed form if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `row_number()` with an aggregation:

```
select s.*, o.product_id
from shops s join
     (select shop_id, product_id, sum(qty) as qty,
             row_number() over (partition by shop_id order by sum(qty) desc) as rnk
      from orders o
      group by shop_id, product_id
     ) o
     on s.shop_id = o.shop_id
where rnk <= 10;
```

If you want more information for the products (more than the product id), then you can join in the `products` table.

Comment: This gives my the to ten products by shop, but in rows not columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look in [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) function to create pivot tables. AFAIK it isn't possible to create dynamic columns, but give a try.