# How do I Separate One Column values into Multiple rows based on condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to Seperate column values into multiple rows based on Condition. Resultant table will show in `Grid view`. I tried with `Count(*)` in multiple `select` statements but not what i expected. Thanks in advance

Table: **RegistrationReport**

```
   Date                 Type
-----------------------------------------
02/05/2015                A
04/05/2015                B
04/05/2015                C
05/05/2015                A
```

I need output like this:

```
Date                 Type 1   Type 2   Type 3 
--------------------------------------------------
02/05/2015              A        -        -
04/05/2015              -        B        - 
04/05/2015              -        -        C  
05/05/2015              A        -        - 
--------------------------------------------------
Total:                  2        1         1
```

Comment: Tons of examples is available on SO. See for "pivot" statement.

Comment: I am Not using any LINQ

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Transpose Rows as Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099198/sql-transpose-rows-as-columns)

Comment: @Nani, you should **accept** working solution of below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below mentioned simple query to get *Total* as well.

```
;with CTE as(
    SELECT Date
        ,case when Type = 'A' then 'A' else '-' end as 'Type_1'
        , case when Type = 'B' then 'B' else '-' end as 'Type_2'
        , case when Type = 'C' then 'C' else '-' end as 'Type_3'
    FROM RegistrationReport
)

select cast(Date as varchar(20))Date
    ,Type_1
    ,Type_2
    ,Type_3
from CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total:'
    ,CAST(SUM(case when Type_1= 'A' then 1 else 0 end)as varchar(10))
    ,CAST(SUM(case when Type_2= 'B' then 1 else 0 end)as varchar(10))
    ,CAST(SUM(case when Type_3= 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar(10))
FROM CTE
```

You will get required output!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the number of columns, and it is relatively few, I think the easiest solution is to just self join:

```
Select distinct Cast(coalesce(a.date, b.date, c.date) as varchar) as Date
  , isnull(a.Type, '--') as Type1 
  , isnull(b.Type, '--') as Type2
  , isnull(c.Type, '--') as Type3 
from Table a
full outer join Table b
  on a.date = b.date
full outer join Table c
  on isnull(a.date, b.date) = c.date
where isnull(a.type, 'A') = 'A' 
  and isnull(b.type, 'B') = 'B' 
  and isnull(c.type, 'C') = 'C'

union all

select 'Total'
  , count(distinct case when type = 'A' then Date end)
  , count(distinct case when type = 'B' then Date end)
  , count(distinct case when type = 'C' then Date end)
from Table
```