# efficient query to group by one field and put all other fields in the row SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, mariadb

Imagine the result of a query is something like the following:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | count   | type   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | 20      | a      |
|  1 | 30      | b      |
|  1 | 10      | c      |
|  2 | 05      | a      |
|  2 | 20      | b      |
|  2 | 40      | c      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

and the expected result:

```
+----+---------+--------+------+
| id | a       | b      | c    |
+----+---------+--------+------+
|  1 | 20      | 30     | 10   |
|  2 | 05      | 20     | 40   |
+----+---------+--------+------+
```

I know some solutions which are complex using Cursor, Variables, Join and etc. I would like to find the most efficient one, otherwise I will handle it from the application layer.

Comment: I removed T-SQL based on a preponderance of evidence.  You should tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Transpose Rows as Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099198/sql-transpose-rows-as-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when type = 'a' then count else 0 end) as a,
       sum(case when type = 'b' then count else 0 end) as b,
       sum(case when type = 'c' then count else 0 end) as c
from t
group by id;
```