# Make name column in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I am looking for an efficient way to convert rows to columns in SQL. Can the name of the column depend on the line change? Here is my example:

Name table films and Visitors

```
Id | film
0  | comedy 
1  | horror 
2  | drama
```

```
Id | visitors
0  | 3
1  | 10
2  | 4
0  | 8
1  | 5
2  | 1
```

I must current sum of comedy, drama, horror where the column names reflects the category of films currently in use. I don't know how.. Could you write this? Please

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: The two answers make different things because it is not quite clear what you are expecting. Please clarify and add some expected output

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just want `join` and `group by`:

```
select f.film, sum(v.visitors)
from visitors v left join
     film f
     on v.id = f.id
group by f.film;
```

If this is what you want, this is a basic SQL query.  `JOIN` is a fundamental concept and you should spend some time learning SQL.  There are many books, tutorials, videos, and other resources available for this purpose.

Comment: Interesting, the different interpretations :) In my opinion the phrase "convert rows to columns" triggers the pivot. But maybe you are right and it is that basic. Perhaps the TO adds an expected output...

Answer (score 0):

For static 3 categories:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a48d03995b85a60f66fe9b86c2c8b30d)

```
SELECT
    SUM(visitors) FILTER (WHERE id = 0) AS comedy, 
    SUM(visitors) FILTER (WHERE id = 1) AS horror, 
    SUM(visitors) FILTER (WHERE id = 2) AS drama
FROM films
```

Comment: How do I change the script so that the name of the column will depend on the name of the movie category? When someone, for example, changes the comedies for a triller, then I would have to manually correct the name of the column. How could I not do this manually?

Comment: @Nemezis First please let us know if this is the result you are expecting in principle?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for it exactly. Thanks!

Comment: @Nemezis Unfortunately this is not that simple in Postgres. But you may have a look at this question where the problem is being discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099198/sql-transpose-rows-as-columns