# Restructure the SQL query based on some column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose there's a table like this:

```
    +-------+-------+-------+
    |YEAR   |Name   |Score  |
    +-------+-------+-------+
    |2019   |Bob    |80     |
    |2019   |David  |90     |
    |2019   |Green  |92     |
    |2019   |Tom    |85     |
    |2020   |Bob    |79     |
    |2020   |David  |87     |
    |2020   |Green  |98     |
    |2020   |Tom    |90     |
    +-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to write a sql query, and the desired output will look like this:

```
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |Date   |Bob    |David  |Green  |Tom    |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |2019   |80     |90     |92     |85     |
    |2020   |79     |87     |98     |90     |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Any help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Transpose Rows as Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099198/sql-transpose-rows-as-columns)

Comment: If you don't know the specific list of names, you will need dynamic SQL.  Your question requires a database tag.  But if you google your database with "dynamic pivot" you can probably find example code.

Comment: What's the difference between `pivot` and `transpose` ? (ps: I am applying sql query on a mysql table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed Name as nm, Year as yr. Try this:

```
Select distinct yr Date,
MAX(CASE WHEN nm = 'Bob' THEN score  END) OVER (PARTITION BY yr)Bob,
MAX(CASE WHEN nm = 'David' THEN score  END) OVER (PARTITION BY yr) David,
MAX(CASE WHEN nm = 'Green' THEN score  END) OVER (PARTITION BY yr)Green,
MAX(CASE WHEN nm = 'Tom' THEN score  END) OVER (PARTITION BY yr)Tom
from table
where yr in ('2019', '2020');
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+-------+-------+-----+
| date | Bob | David | Green | Tom |
+------+-----+-------+-------+-----+
| 2019 |  80 |    90 |    92 |  85 |
+------+-----+-------+-------+-----+
| 2020 |  79 |    87 |    98 |  90 |
+------+-----+-------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `PIVOT` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
PIVOT(
    MAX(SCORE) 
    FOR YEAR
    IN ( 
        2019,
        2020
    )
)
ORDER BY NAME;
```

You can check this [link](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/) for more detail.

Comment: I think you meant MAX(SCORE) instead of  COUNT(SCORE).

Comment: My bad, I fixed it.